# retain dropdown select values after refresh with php session variables

Tags: php, html

Iam trying to make a dropdown select "sticky", basically I need to retain the value of the dropdown select in a session variable, then use the session variable in the doprdown select, so that when the page is refreshed, the value is retained in the dropdown select. I am trying to do this in php.

Here is the code for the select :

```
<?php
    $countryId = isset($_POST['country']) ? $_POST['country'] : '';
    asort($dirs);
    reset($dirs);
    echo '<option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Country</option>';
    foreach ($dirs as $p => $w):
        $selected = $countryId === $w ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option value="' . $w . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $w . '</option>';
    endforeach;
?>
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

make a second file called `savesession.php`

```
<?php
   if (isset($_GET['country_option'])) $_SESSION['country_option'] = $_GET['country_option'];
```

then change your code to be

```
<?php

   $countryId = isset($_POST['country']) ? $_POST['country'] : isset($_SESSION['country_option']) ? $_SESSION['country_option'] : '';
   asort($dirs);
   reset($dirs); 
   echo '<option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Country</option>';
   foreach($dirs as $p => $w):
       $selected = $countryId===$w ? 'selected' : '';
       echo '<option value="'.$w.'" '.$selected.'>'.$w.'</option>';
   endforeach;
?>
<script>
   function onDropDownChange(){

         var dd = document.getElementById("dropdownID");
         var selectedItem = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;

         var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
         ajax.open("GET", "yourpage.com/savesession.php?country_option=" + selectedItem, true);

        ajax.send();
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {    
                  var data = ajax.responseText;    
              } 
        }
   }
</script>
```

then add an `onchange="onDropDownChange"` and `id="dropdownID"` to the `<select>` so that it calls a javascript function onDropDownChange

Comment: my mistake, did miss session_start, now works fine, many thanks!